# How can I change the value of an a html value which has the same name as a group of others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a group of buttons with different values but same name (says "save"). When one of this button is clicked, a jquery event is triggered and sends the value of that exact button with an ajax call to the server. When the server responds with a success, I would like the value of that same clicked button to change into "saved". I have written a little function that does that, but the problem is that when you click on one of those buttons that say "save" and it's a success, all the values of the other buttons change into "saved". How can I change only the value of the clicked button and instead of all the buttons with the same name?

Here's my html:

```
<button class="homemade" name="saveArticle" value="v1">Save</button>

<button class="homemade" name="saveArticle" value="v2">Save</button>
```

Here's my Jquery function:

```
$(function() {
    $('[name="saveArticle"]').bind('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('/articles/save', {
            article_id: this.value,
        }, function(data) {
            $("[name='saveArticle']").text(data.message);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: How about using an id?

Comment: number of buttons are fix or its dynamic?

Comment: @LeeTaylor, yes, I have tried to work with an id, but honestly, I am not very familiar with Javascript and I genuinely don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: @Arjun, the number is dynamic.

Comment: @MurphyAdam If you're not familiar with HTML `id`s or how to target them in JavaScript, you should consider re-visiting HTML/JS fundamentals. Even this low-to-medium complexity jQuery snippet should be difficult to fully understand without a firm grasp on the underlying concepts in play.

Comment: @esqew, yes, you're absolutely right. I have began and then I just faced this problem. I'll surely keep on. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use arrow functions then you can just use `this` to refer to the clicked button.

```
$(function() {
    $('[name="saveArticle"]').bind('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('/articles/save', {
            article_id: this.value,
        }, (data)=>{
            $(this).text(data.message);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

alternatively you could use the event target.

```
$(function() {
    $('[name="saveArticle"]').bind('click', function(event) {
        $.getJSON('/articles/save', {
            article_id: this.value,
        }, function(data) {
            $(event.target).text(data.message);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: @I wrestled a bear once, (cool username btw), thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn’t that do the trick to give you access to the element that was clicked?

```
$(function() {
    $('[name="saveArticle"]').bind('click', function() {
        // here `this` points to element on which event fired
        $(this) // <-- creates jQuery object of it
    });
  });
```

Comment: inside the inner function `this` won't refer to the button anymore, it will refer to the window.

Comment: Ah, nested functions. I missed that one.